# React Native Splash Screen image too big and offscreen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I installed react-native-splash-screen and correctly setup everything but my logo image is shown streched and offscreen (appears too big).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhWM9.jpg

I used App Icon Generator website and placed the generated images into each drawable folder with the correct names:
https://www.appicon.co/

My launch_screen.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/launch_screen"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `centerInside` for `scaleType`.

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

See all [options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) for scaling.

Answer (score 0):

change the scaleType like as

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by incorporating android:scaleType="centerInside"